# C/C++ interop between _Complex and std::complex

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I have some C DSP libraries which use `complex [T]` types for complex numbers.  I want to call these from a C++ application which uses `std::complex<T>`.

After reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540346/1156377) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25348164/1156377), and §26.4 of [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), I tried an experiment:

```
extern "C" {
#include <complex.h>
// Using _Complex or __complex__ since C's "complex" type doesn't exist in C++
void cfunc(_Complex float x);
}
#include <complex>

void test()
{
        std::complex<float> z;
        cfunc(reinterpret_cast<float[2]>(z));
}
```

And tried to compile it with `CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"`.  I got the following from GCC 6.3.1:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘std::complex<float>’ to type ‘float [2]’
  cfunc(reinterpret_cast<float[2]>(z));
```

Is this a compiler bug or am I misunderstanding something?  How would one use C functions which take `complex [T]` arguments, given C++ code using `std::complex<T>` types?  Currently, I use a dirty hack to work around this issue but I'd prefer a clean way.

I tried compiling with `-std=c++14` just in case this feature had missed C++11 somehow (despite posts quoting it from the C++11 standard) but I get the same result.

---

> 26.4 Complex numbers [complex.numbers]
>
> 1. The header `<complex>` defines a class template, and numerous functions for representing and manipulating
>      complex numbers.
> 2. The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other than float, double, or long double
>      is unspecified. The specializations `complex<float>`, `complex<double>`, and `complex<long double>` are
>      literal types (3.9).
> 3. If the result of a function is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
>      type, the behavior is undefined.
> 4. If z is an lvalue expression of type cv `std::complex<T>` then:
>
>    4.1. the expression `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)` shall be well-formed,
>
>    4.2. `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` shall designate the real part of z, and
>
>    4.3. `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` shall designate the imaginary part of z.

Comment: Read the notes on the `<complex.h>` header file: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header : _" (deprecated) simply includes the header <complex>"_ ... _" <ccomplex> (since C++11)(deprecated in C++17) "_

Comment: @RichardCritten: Would you mind pasting a snippet of the relevant section so we don't all have to chase it down?

Comment: @RichardCritten : Thanks.  In my case, `complex.h` is included by the C headers rather than the C++ code.  I added it in the experiment since it'll be included by my application (via the C library headers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  problem is you are trying to cast to a value instead of a reference.  The standard guarantees that

```
reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)
```

Is well formed.  It does not say

```
reinterpret_cast<cv T[2]>(z)
```

Is valid.  To make you code compile you need to change the cast to cast to a reference which gives you

```
cfunc(reinterpret_cast<float(&)[2]>(z));
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1787ef126acd4c79)</kbd>

Comment: Ahhhhh  me misinterpreting what the round parentheses meant!  ` cfunc(*reinterpret_cast<float(&)[2]>(z));` compiles (note the de-referencing after the cast, if the C library expects a single complex by value as in my test case).  Your answer also explains why there is the mention of z being an lvalue in the standard.

Comment: @MarkKCowan Yep.  This requires it be an lvaule so you can bind to the reference.

Comment: How would I pass a `std::complex<T> *` to a C function which takes `complex T *`?

Comment: @MarkKCowan Should be able to use: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a598181914271d44

Comment: That works if the function takes `float(*)[2]` argument, but for a (C) function which takes pointer-to-complex, it doesn't seem to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a08b9e918722da5

Comment: @MarkKCowan I have very little experience with C.  I'm not sure how you will be able to cast it as I do not understand the C type.

Comment: Ok.  Currently, I have proxy C++ functions which internally declare `extern ret_type c_function(args.... )` where the pointer-to-complex types are replaced with void pointers, and the proxy function calls this using casts.  It works, but it's just ugly/WET and I was hoping that I'd been missing something obvious.